# ¿Cómo solucionar el Error 419 laravel CSFR si esta en el form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

He tenido problemas muy seguido con el error 419 la sesion expiro, he buscado por muchos lados y todo las posibles soluciones se implementaron durante el desarrollo para evitar problemas.

**Nota: es un proyecto en producción**

1. Csfr en el form se encuentra lo intende las siguientes formas @csfr, {{ csrf_field()
   }}, {!! {{ csrf_token() }} !!}

   ```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{     
       route('users.post.score') }}">
       {{ csrf_field() }}            
   </form>
   ```
2. En el archivo .env SESSION_DOMAIN tengo el dominio de mi proyecto ejemplo SESSION_DOMAIN =diminio.com
3. En el header tengo tengo el token:
4. Con jquery y ajax

`<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function() {$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} }); }); </script>`

4. La configuración de mi archivo session la modifique a database driver, se crearon las migraciones y tablas, pero el error persiste, se realizo el cambio en el archivo .env SESSION_DRIVER=database
5. En el archivo se cambio a true lo siguiente'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true)
6. El tiempo de vida de la sesión es el siguiente 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
7. Tengo implementado en cloudflare las siguientes reglas

[image: reglas de cloudflare headers secure]

9.He ejecutado los siguientes comandos al modificar algo en el backend:

```
sudo php artisan cache:clear
sudo php artisan view:clear
sudo php artisan config:clear
sudo php artisan route:clear
```

10. Algo que sucede es un navegador modo incógnito no ocurre el problema del error 419, si es el problema de chache y cookies por ejecutar los comandos anteriores ¿Qué podria hacer?
11. En otros sitio me dicen ejecutar php artisan key:generate pero ¿Qué consecuencias tendría esto?

Espero su ayuda, por favor.

Comment: La clave creo que está en el punto 10. Si en un navegador modo incógnito no ocurre el problema del error 419, es por la cache del navegador. Prueba con ctrl+f5, o limpia la cache del navegador

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ  y gracias por tu respuesta, eso es lo primero que intente refrescar la web, pero el problema son los usuarios que han entrado al sitio y tienen una sesión ya. Yo pensé en lo siguiente, correr  php artisan key:generate para que todas la sesiones fallen, volver a configurar session con driver file, eliminar todos los archivos de sesiones en el directorio storage/framework/sessions/ y nunca ejecutar en producion sudo php artisan cache:clear

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` NO es nada recomendable para un proyecto en producción.
Puedes crear un comando que ejecute:
`Artisan::call('cache:clear');
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table(config('session.table', 'sessions'))->truncate();`

en mi caso lo llamo con  `php artisan session:flush`

Comment: @Orici me podrías decir por favor cache:clear limpia toda la cache de la app y digamos que rompe la sessiones creadas con la cache que se acaba de eliminar ¿estoy en lo correcto? por otro lado $request->session()->flush(); seria lo mismo entrar a storage/framework/sessions/ y eliminar todos los archivos de sessioens creadas ¿estoy mal o solamente se aplica para la sesión vigente?